# Can i use one-hot vector for named entity tags to concate with word embedding to improve neural machine translation?

Tags: nlp, machine-translation

i'm using word features such as additional input for my nmt model. I used gensim to create pretrained embedding for each features and concated them with my word embedding vectors. So the question is can i use named entity tags as word feature and concate named entity tag one-hot vector to word embedding vector ? Main idea come from this [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/U16-1001)

Example:

word embedding vector: [1,2,3,4]

pos tag: [5,6,7]

named entity tag: [0,1,0]

=> final embedding vector: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,0]

Comment: Yes you could. You will have to figure out representing the start and end of an entity in case it spans over multiple words.

Comment: maybe i will create one hot vector for each entity tag in IOB format

Comment: Yes that would work.